# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : - data still coming through

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm very new to JSON and JSONP.

I've read through each of the posts that are recommend by the SO search for this error, but I can't seem to get a handle on it.

I have the following code to grab data from an EXTERNAL website:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://url.com/authenticate?login=test&apiKey=test",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success:function(json){
      console.log("login successful");
      }
  });
```

When I load the page, I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

and when I click on the error in Chrome, I see

```
{"Status":{"Code":"2","Message":"Authentication Succeeded","Success":"true"}}
```

with a little red x after `"true"})`

From this, it seems as though I have succeeded in logging in, but I'm doing something else wrong because my `console.log("login successful");` never fires.  What am I doing wrong?

## P.S.

I've tried `dataType: 'json'` but I get the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` as I'm on a different server, so I went back to jsonP as this is cross-domain.

I've also tried the above url as `url: "https://url.com/authenticate?login=test&apiKey=test&callback=?",` as I've read I need a callback, but I don't really understand what the functionality of `callback` is and either way, the error that gets returned (whether `&callback=?` is in there or not) is:

```
authenticateUser?login=test&apiKey=test&callback=jQuery111107732549801003188_1423867185396…:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

so it's adding the callback in either way....

Also, from the API I'm trying to access:
"this uses the REST protocol, and provides data structured as XML or JSON"

*This is not a duplicate of the linked post as the information in the linked post does a great job of explaining what JSONP **is**, but doesn't answer my specific question regarding why I get data back (so my call is successful,) but why I still get an error and cause my script to stop.*

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate question - I read through the entire post you linked, and there's some great info it, so thank you.  Still, I say it's not a duplicate because my question is not answered anywhere in that post.

Comment: The answer to your question can be derived from the other question: JSONP is nothing else but dynamically evaluating JavaScript received from the server. The response you receive is not valid JavaScript, hence you get that error.

Comment: Logout and go directly to the URL from browser and see what it returns

Comment: You get the error because it is NOT JSONP. That is JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for your response, I really do appreciate it.  Would you possibly be able to help me understand why the response is not valid JavaScript?  My code looks exactly like much of the code I've seen in other posts and tutorials, and the data I'm getting back from the server is exactly what I get when I type this URL directly into the address bar, so it's working technically...

Comment: If the 3rd party does not support JSONP and it does not have CORS enabled, than there is nothing you can do with your JavaScript call.  You are going to have to use a proxy.

Comment: @epascarello , so am I going about this entirely the wrong way?  The webpage says `"this uses the REST protocol, and provides data structured as XML or JSON`.  They obviously developed the API to be used by people outside of their domain, so it makes no sense that I can't write something to connect to it and get data.  Is an AJAX call utilizing JSON the wrong way to get data back?

Comment: FWIW: just  type `{"foo": "bar"}` into the console, you will get an a syntax error. That's because `{...}` is interpreted as a block. Plain JSON by itself is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you're sending the AJAX request doesn't implement JSONP. It ignores the `callback=` parameter, and just returns ordinary JSON. But when the browser tries to process this as JSONP, it gets a syntax error because it's not properly formatted. JSONP is a JSON object wrapped in a call to the specified callback function, e.g. it should be sending back:

```
jQuery111107732549801003188_1423867185396({...});
```

where `{...}` is the JSON object you're trying to retrieve. But it's just returning `{...}`.

You should implement this using a PHP script on your own server. It can be as simple as this:

```
<?php
$username = urlencode($_POST['user']);
readfile("https://url.com/authenticate?login=$username&apiKey=test");
```

Then your AJAX call would be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yourscript.php", 
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { user: "test" },
    success: function(json) {
        console.log("login successful");
    }
});
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me though.  This is a company that my company works with who specifically gave me access to their API.  If they don't support JSONP, how am I supposed to use the API???  And if JSONP isn't  supported, why do I get back a string that shows my session authenticated?

Comment: You're still sending the request to the server, just as if you were submitting a form, so it performs the authentication normally. You just can't read the response, because it's not coming back in the correct way. The browser blocks cross-domain AJAX responses. JSONP is a trick, instead of the browser trying to read the response using AJAX, it creates a `<script>` tag that points to the URL. That's why the server has to send back valid Javascript code for you to execute.

Comment: The whole point of this is that the server has to take special action to allow the API to be used from another domain. Either it adds your domain to its `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, or it has to implement JSONP.

Comment: Okay, I'm happy to go back to my contact and ask to be added to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but I want to make sure that's my only option for solving this so I don't look stupid....... It kinda seemed like when they gave me the username and password to access the API, that was all I would need, especially since the command works from the address bar just fine.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing it directly from the browser, because then the API key will be visible to the user. You should use the API from a script on your server.

Comment: oh totally - I was saying that if I go type in the exact same thing as my code says into the browser, I get back the response I'm looking for.  Inside my code, I'll have it (eventually) inside a separate .js file with some other code so it's hidden from the user, (and it's organized better with my other scripts...)

Comment: All `.js` files are visible to the user. Open up Developer Tools, go to the Sources tab, and you can see them all.

Comment: so inside a php script then, (I'm assuming that's how I would do something `on the server`

Comment: Yes. If you do it there, using `cURL` or `file_get_contents`, it should work just fine.

Comment: by `it` do you mean `the whole getting data out of the API` thing?  Cause if so I'm going to read up on both of those things right now!

Comment: dude, thank you so much for taking time out of your day to help me with this.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: so doing it this way, I'm getting an output in my php file of `2Authentication Succeededtrue`, but my script is still failing...  I have: `$.ajax({
    url: '/login.php',    
    dataType: 'JSON',        
    type: 'POST',
    success: function() { console.log("BOOYA"); },                                                                                                                                                                                       
    error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); },
  });  `  and in my php file I just have the username and password defined there.

Comment: I've also tried this using your exact code, (modified URL of course...) and I get the same result, (of no `console.log` as there's no error call)

Comment: alright - I dug into the response and found that it's XML, (even without the &fmt=XML` flag... not sure why they're responding in XML by default, but I changed the datatype to XML and it WORKS!!!  yay!  Thank you times 1000.